# Best way to remove Devise?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, devise

I've been having some problems with the reset password part of devise so is there an easy way to remove it?

Comment: What do you mean 'remove it'? Do you not want to use the functionality no more? And what problems are you facing?

Comment: How did you install it? What have you tried?

Comment: I do want to use the functionality although it's not working and I can't figure out why. When I click on "Send me reset password instructions" I get an ArguemntError

Comment: Why not post a question with everything pertaining to the ArgumentError?

Answer (score 3):

You get the ArgumentError when trying to reset the password because you have not set devise properly

In "config/environments/development.rb" you need to set the host, for example:

```
config.action_mailer.default_url_options = { :host => 'localhost:3000' }
```

Read the whole getting started here: https://github.com/plataformatec/devise#getting-started

---

If you really need to remove Devise:

- Delete the gem from Gemfile
- Delete the tables if you ran the migrations
- Delete the generated
  views, controllers, models and mailers (if you generated them)

Answer (score 0):

Don't remove it, I use devise everytime I need authentication and have never ran into any issues, that weren't easy to fix.

My bet is that you haven't followed the instructions correctly. After running

`rails g devise:install`

You need to follow the instructions printed out in the command line.

If you really need to remove it do the following:

1. Remove from Gemfile
2. Remove Authentication links and logic from controllers, views and models if you had them.
3. Remove Devise tables from Database