# How can I completly Remove devise from a rails 7 app?

Tags: devise, ruby-on-rails-7

I want to remove devise authentication from my app and use a different authentication method. Do I just follow this [Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13998527/22852557), but it says nothing about the devise migration file

I tried to run a rollback to the devise migration but ran into this error `ActiveRecord::IrreversibleMigration` caused by this method in the migration file

```
  def self.down
    # By default, we don't want to make any assumption about how to roll back a migration when your
    # model already existed. Please edit below which fields you would like to remove in this migration.
    raise ActiveRecord::IrreversibleMigration
  end
```